# I think I have problem with static methods. How do I fix this error?

Tags: java

```
public class ConversionTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double g = gallonsToPints(4.0);
        double f = feetToInches(2.0);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Conversion
{
   public double gallon;
   public double feet;

   public static double gallonsToPints(double ga)
   {
       gallon = ga;
       return gallon * 8;
   }

   public static double feetToInches(double fe)
   {
       feet = fe;
       return feet * 12;
   }

}
```

ConversionTester.java: Line 7: You may have forgotten to declare gallonsToPints(double) or it's out of scope.
ConversionTester.java: Line 8: You may have forgotten to declare feetToInches(double) or it's out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, either will work. The first is **explicitly** naming the class like

```
double g = Conversion.gallonsToPints(4.0);
double f = Conversion.feetToInches(2.0);
```

The second would be to add `static import`(s). Before `public class ConversionTester` like,

```
static import Conversion.gallonsToPints;
static import Conversion.feetToInches;
```